# Laravel Blade accessing data

Tags: php, laravel-5

my controller:

```
 $this->data['naskleng'] = json_decode($resource->packages, true);
```

my View:

```
@forelse($naskleng as $packageDetail)

{!! $packageDetail['package_list]['name'] !!}

@empty
   <h1>KUUK</h1>
@endforelse
```

if dd($packageDetail['package_list]) and the result

```
[{"id":"4h","name":"4 Hours leak","rate":"350000","commission_type":"fixed","commission":"50000"},{"id":"7h","name":"7 Hours","rate":"550000","commission_type":"fixed","commission":"50000"},{"id":"10h","name":"10 Hours","rate":"700000","commission_type":"fixed","commission":"100000"}]
```

### And this is the whole data. dd($this->data);

```
array:11 [▼
"pageTitle" => "Users"
"pageIcon" => "fa-id-card"
"pageSubTitle" => "List of Users in the system."
"windowTitle" => "packages"
"service" => Service {#493 ▶}
"naskleng" => array:1 [▼
 0 => array:13 [▼
  "id" => 5
  "country" => "ID"
  "service_id" => 4
  "package_id" => 1
  "min_rate" => null
  "max_rate" => null
  "commission_type" => "fixed"
  "commission" => null
  "min_purchase" => "0"
  "package_list" => "[{"id":"4h","name":"4 Hours leak","rate":"350000","commission_type":"fixed","commission":"50000"},{"id":"7h","name":"7 Hours","rate":"550000","commission_type":"fixed","commission":"50000"},{"id":"10h","name":"10 Hours","rate":"700000","commission_type":"fixed","commission":"100000"}] ◀"
  "translations" => []
  "configurations" => []
  "availabilities" => []
 ]
```

**how to accessing package_list data and print it to view**

```
id = 4h
name = 4 hour leak
rate = 35000
commission_type = fixed
```

Comment: You're going to have to `json_decode($packageDetail['package_list'])` before you can use its contents, as it appears to be a JSON string.

Comment: **thank you learn mode = ON :D**

Answer (score 0):

Try this {!! $packageDetail['package_list']['name'] !!}

I think the problem is that you miss a ' after "package_list" so that it not work

Goodluck!

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo, but I think OP has something more significant going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 dd($packageDetail['package_list']->name)
```

Thanks